# Python: Using a variable from my function in main

Tags: python

I am looking to call my list that is formed in my readingAverage(filepath) function into my writingAverage() function. I get an error saying that average_list2 is not defined. Where am i going wrong and how can i improve it.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import os
from itertools import islice

path = '//haeo1ims1005/controlsprojects$/BOD INFO/ROBOT DATA/AXIS/137'
os.chdir(path)



def readingAverage(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        average = f.readlines()[46:53]
        average_join = '\n'.join(average)

        
        j1 = average_join[5:16]
        j2 = average_join[46:57]
        j3 = average_join[87:98]
        j4 = average_join[128:139]
        j5 = average_join[169:180]
        j6 = average_join[210:221]
        j7 = average_join[251:262]

        average_list = []
        average_list.append(j1)
        average_list.append(j2)
        average_list.append(j3)
        average_list.append(j4)
        average_list.append(j5)
        average_list.append(j6)
        average_list.append(j7)

        average_list2 = []
        average_list2.append(average_list)
        print(average_list2)

def writingAverage(average_list2):
    with open('C:/Users/DunningJ3/Desktop/practice.txt', 'a') as wf:
        writer = csv.writer(wf)
        writer.writerow(average_list2)

        



#Beginning main code

for file in os.listdir():
    #check if file is in text format or not
    if file.endswith(".ls"):
        filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
        #calling the read function
        readingAverage(filepath)

writingAverage(average_list2)
```

Comment: You need to put the list initializations outside the function. That way they'll be global variables, and you won't empty them for each file.

Comment: Depending on how large the file is, I would use something like `average = list(islice(f, 46, 53))` so that you don't need to read all 100k lines just to get a few of the first 53.

Answer (score 0):

I see two different ways to do that:

1. As suggested by @Barmar you can put the variable definition
   outside the function. Note that you're not really using a standard
   "main" Python function. You are just executing everything in the
   same block. So that should fix it.
2. Return the list `average_list2` in the end of your function, and assign it to another variable. Then pass this new variable to the second function. Like this:

```py
    def readingAverage(filepath):
        {...}
        return average_list2
    
    for file in os.listdir():
    #check if file is in text format or not
    if file.endswith(".ls"):
        filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
        #calling the read function
        avg_list_2 = readingAverage(filepath)
    
     writingAverage(avg_list_2)
```